# Select records only if previous row coloumn is different SQL in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I have a problem with MySql, that I can't find if is possible to solve with MySql.

I have this table for example:

```
|cod | value    |
| 1  |  value1  |
| 1  |  value2  |
| 2  |  value3  |
| 1  |  value4  |
| 5  |  value5  |
| 5  |  value6  |
| 2  |  value7  |
```

The result that I would like:

```
|cod | value    |
| 1  |  value1  |
| 2  |  value3  |
| 1  |  value4  |
| 5  |  value5  |
| 2  |  value7  |
```

So get row only if it is has **cod** different from previous record.

So my question is:
Is possibile doing this with Mysql?
Is there any way for know the previous row value in MySQL?

Comment: `SELECT cod, value FROM tbl_name GROUP BY cod`?

Comment: thankyou, no, because with double 2 for example, it return only one value I'm trying setting a variable.

Answer (score 0):

I'have solved in this way, but I don't know if it is the best way:

```
set @last := 'NULL';
Select cod, test.value, @last := cod as previous
from test
where @last != cod
```

Some one more skilled in SQL could suggest me if it is a valid method?